# Even Vertical and horizontal align flexbox

Tags: html, css, alignment, flexbox

Basically I have three items aligned in a row with flexboxes and it worked however there is a weird issue with the vertical align.
Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of alignment issue]
 **[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x6tkhzfw/1/)**

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.points {
  flex: 1;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.p1 {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.p2 {
  align-self: center;
}

.p3 {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="textcenter">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <h4>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</h4>
</div>

<div class="flex-container bg">
  <div class="points p1 textcenter">
    <h3>Support for most popular<br>languages and frameworks</h3>
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div class="points p2 textcenter">
    <h3>Open Source</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="points p3 textcenter">
    <h3>Constantly Growing</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance,
Diego

Comment: I'm also having a weird issue with your example, Diego. No matter how hard I try, I can't inspect the code you used to produce that image. Please provide a [mcve] so I could help you out.

Comment: Maybe you have default margin/padding on the element in the last flex child?

Comment: Or `top` + `relative`, a simple `<br>`, a pseudo element, a `transform`, `line-height`, `align-self` and the list goes on. I prefer inspecting to guessing. Takes a lot less time to answer & fix.

Comment: Sorry Andrei, I'll make a fiddle real quick

Comment: why you are use p1,p2 p3  class ??

Comment: @Sumitpatel point 1 2 and 3

Comment: i solve your problem but without  `align-self: flex-start;` & `align-self: center;` & `align-self: flex-end;`   this any problem ??. i know your p1,p2,p3 your point but inside class not require style

Comment: @Sumitpatel can you link a fiddle or something similar?

Comment: @DiegoEann What Sumit's answer does not explain is that `align-self`, when used on a flex child, refers to the position within the current flex cell, not to the position within the parent, which is how most people tend to think it works. I also don't find it particularly useful myself and find there's quite a bit of confusion regarding proper usage and purpose of `align-self`. If you want to control their order, you need to use the `order` attribute, also part of `flexbox` spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Revise Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6tkhzfw/5/)**

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

.points {
  flex: 1;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}

p1,p2,p3 {
}
```

```html
<div class="textcenter">
   <h1>tutorial-db</h1>
   <h4>The Ultimate Coding Recource Database</h4>
</div>

<div class="flex-container bg">
   <div class="points p1 textcenter">
      <h3>Support for most popular<br>languages and frameworks</h3>
      <p></p>
   </div>

   <div class="points p2 textcenter">
      <h3>Open Source</h3>
   </div>

   <div class="points p3 textcenter">
      <h3>Constantly Growing</h3>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I hope you don't take this as a critique, but as a suggestion, if you ever want to work on improving the quality of your answers, you could find some good general advice in [answer]. For this one, in particular, *"try this"* type of answers tend to generally be regarded as lower quality (even if the solution is the right one) because it makes it clear the answer is based on guess/hunch/feeling rather than actually understanding the problem. Additionally, you could try to briefly explain the principle: why you think that particular solution would work. Best regards,

Comment: thank you @AndreiGheorghiu for suggest . never repeat this mistake.